Link an HTML page with changed content on it
The answer to this question may be simple, but due to my inability to phrase it very well, I've been having a hard time finding search results on what I'm looking for.
Here is my issue: my page operates by displaying plain HTML files (that is HTML files with little to no CSS styling) onto a "mother" page that has all the CSS styling to make everything look nice. For example: let's say on https://mywebsite.com I have the following code:
<a href="#pictures" onclick="changecontent(1); return false;">click for pictures</a>
and if (page == 1) $("#content").load("/pictures.html");
This works just fine. However, if I want to link people specifically to my pictures section on my page...how can I do that without linking the actual pictures.html? I've changed return false to return true and while it changes my webpage's URL after clicking the link to this:
https://mywebsite.com/#pictures
actually putting https://mywebsite.com/#pictures into the URL bar just takes me to the default https://mywebsite.com. So, how do I go about linking a page with changed content on it? Many thanks!

So I think you're asking how to trigger your content loading operation when the page is first loaded and #pictures is part of the URL? Is that what you mean?

Your question is unclear... what should than https://mywebsite.com/#pictures (in the address-bar) actually do? Open immediately the "main" page with dynamically and automatically inserted "pictures" into #content?

Also... I find changecontent("pictures") a better, direct, and more developer friendly approach than changecontent(1) and have to use useless if/else statements

What you're looking for is Dynamic routing using # fragment identifier (hash). It involves the History API. Otherwise you'll soon realize that the user can also land on an URL with such a fragment, but also navigate the browsing history with the prev/next buttons and your basic idea would fail.

@RokoC.Buljan My apologies for being unclear. You got it, though! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Here are some examples on various ways to load the page
<a href="/pictures.html" class="contentLink">click for pictures</a> 

$(() => {
  // clicking will load it into content - do NOT do this to have the link go to the page
  $('.contentLink').on('click',(e) => { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    $("#content").load(e.target.closest('a').attr('href'));
  });
  // if page == 1 on page load, load the first of those links into content
  if (page == 1) {
    $("#content").load($('.contentLink').eq(0).attr('href'));
  })
});


(nitpicking) jQuery($ => { is a better DOM ready than $(() => { since it creates a safe scope for the common $ alias ;) PS... what is page in if (page == 1) {? And why == instead of ===

OP is asking about something else, I believe, and $('.contentLink').eq(0) is bug prone. Read my comments under OP's question.

The if (page == 1) was OP's. I did not change it since I do not know if it is 1 or "1"

Yeah, I have never ever needed jQuery($ => and if you need it, you need it.

add this to your page
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="changecontent(1);">click for pictures</a>

